# Can you advice on using async vs sync read/write small packets very frequently from NetworkStream?

Tags: c#, async-await, networkstream

I'm implementing a communication protocol (Modbus) in C# using NetworkStream: program needs to write small packets (commands) and subsequentially read response (a few bytes) from a connected TCP socket.
I usually use a full async solution when dealing with streams like FileStream or NetworkStream like the following (sample code):

```
Task.Run(async () => 
{
    while (true)
    {
       await stream.WriteAsync(cmdBuffer, ...);
       await stream.ReadAsync(responseBuffer, ...);
       //handle response....
    }
});
```

but I wonder if plain sync read/write (in this specific case ie small packets read/write very frequently) could work pretty much the same:

```
var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.DoWork));
thread.Start();

private void DoWork()
{
    stream.Write(cmdBuffer, ...);
    stream.Read(responseBuffer, ...);
    //handle response....
}
```

I'm right to say that async/await doesn't make much difference in this case?

Comment: Very much depends on the wider context. Why are you explicitly running the code an another thread?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay because I need to poll multiple devices (less than 10): I have a task (or thread depending on the implementation) for each device that continuously takes a command from a queue, sends it to the tcp socket as shown above and read the response

Comment: I suppose the simple answer is that the `async` example will keep threads available whilst I/O happens, whereas the second will block those threads. The sync example, however, will be slightly more efficient on an individual basis. Do you have a collection of devices? Also where are `cmdBuffer` and `responseBuffer` defined? There may be a better solution if you could provide that code.

Comment: Yes, I need to pool a few devices (under 10 connections); I didn't post the code because still need to write it, I mean, I wanted an opinion on the best practice on this use case: I agree with you that the async solution will leave the threads available and I usually I prefer it for this reason but really reading and writing a few bytes over a fast network doesn't actually mean that the task scheduler will end up continuously switching between tasks? at this point, do you agree that blocking a predefined single thread per device would work even better on cpu/memory pressure?

Comment: With so few clients I wouldn't say memory/CPU is a major consideration.

Comment: Two pretty different examples. 1st with loop, 2nd without it. But, its very important to know how long your loop is running. For `Thread`&sync example consider `Task.Run(() => DoWork());`. There's a difference. `Task` runs on a pooled Thread, and all pooled Threads are background Threads. Learn the difference between foreground and background Threads, otherwise it can gift you some surprise.